# Grouping data in chap-links-library

Tags: chap-links-library

I am using chap-links-library in the project I am working on. We are trying to show different kind of activities that a user performed. We want to display the activities and number of times that has been performed by the user.

The initial zoom will be for 12 months and the user can zoom in to day level. I want to group all activities of same type performed in a month and show the cumulative count on initial display. When user zooms in they should be able to see the split up of activities and its count based on the visible range.

Any pointers on how to handle this in chap-links-library will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `rangechange` or `rangechanged` events ([see docs](http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/doc/#Events)), and when the visible range exceeds a certain threshold, replace all data in the Timeline with more coarse grained data when above it, or with the detailed data when below the threshold.

You may want to have a look at the successor of chap-links-library, [vis.js](http://visjs.org). You can find an overview of the main changes here: http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/#successor.